# Setting up tomcat7 in Eclipse Galileo

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I downloaded tomcat7, but I'm at a loss setting it up as a web server manageable through Eclipse 3.5 on Ubuntu 10.10. Any guidance?

Comment: Why the ancient Eclipse version? If you use a current then the support is built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dowload the tomcat plugin from [plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html). Unzip it and move it inside the directory `Eclipse\plugin\`.

Start Eclipse and choose: `“Window” -> “Preferences” -> “Tomcat”`, now select the version you are using (Tomcat 7) and the Tomcat home.

Et voilà!

Ask in the comment if you need additional information.

Regards.

Comment: This doesn't work on Eclipse 3.5 Galileo, it only does in 3.7 Indigo, I had to update.